# Menu doesn't remember user_choice after going through questions

Tags: python

The text is Swedish but the point is:

Have a menu where 1 is a question game, 2 is statistics with globals and 3 is exit.

And part of it is to separate `question` and `question_game`.

My problem?

When you first start it. Everything works. After answering questions you can check stats. Answer again. But you can't use the option 3 to exit the program. It simply restarts the menu.

We are not aloud to use `sys.exit()`.

```
wrong = 0
answered = 0

def main():
    user_choice = ""

    while user_choice != "3":
        print_menu()
        user_choice = input("Ange val: ")

        if user_choice == "1":
            question_game()
        elif user_choice == "2":
            stats()
        elif user_choice == "3":
            print("Tack och hej! Forza Bajen!")
        else:
            print("-"*30)
            print("Du valde ett ogiltigt alternativ. Var god välj mellan 1-3.")       

def print_menu():
    print("-"*30)
    print("Meny - Frågespel")
    print("-"*30)
    print("1. Spela mitt frågespel")
    print("2. Spelstatistik")
    print("3. Avsluta spelet")

def question_game():
    print("-"*30)
    print("Välkommen till frågespelet!")
    print("-"*30)
    question("Vilket är Nordens största publiklag?", "Hammarby")
    question("Vem skrev och sjöng 'Just idag är jag stark'?", "Kenta")
    question("Vad heter Bajens klassiska arena vid Johanneshov?", "Söderstadion")
    print("*"*30)
    print("Tack för att du var med och spela! Du skickas nu tillbaka till huvudmenyn.")
    print("*"*30)

def question(quiz, answer):
    global wrong, answered
    while True:
        quiz = print("Vilket är Nordens största publiklag?") 
        answer = str(input("Ditt svar: "))            
        if answer == "Hammarby" or answer == "hammarby" or answer == "bajen" or answer=="Bajen":
            print("*"*30)
            print("Bra där! Synder eller ej gör gör detsamma, allt för Bajen och allt för mamma!")
            print("*"*30)
            answered = answered + 1

            while True:
                quiz = print("Vem skrev och sjöng 'Just idag är jag stark'?")
                answer = str(input("Ditt svar: "))
                if answer == "Kenta" or answer == "kenta":
                    print("*"*30)
                    print("Bra där! Synder eller ej gör gör detsamma, allt för Bajen och allt för mamma!")
                    print("*"*30)
                    answered = answered + 1

                    while True: 
                        quiz = print("Vad heter Bajens klassiska arena vid Johanneshov?")
                        answer = str(input("Ditt svar: "))
                        if answer == "Söderstadion" or answer == "söderstadion":
                            print("*"*30)
                            print("Bra där! Synder eller ej gör gör detsamma, allt för Bajen och allt för mamma!")
                            print("*"*30)
                            answered = answered + 1
                            while True:
                                main()
                                continue
                        else:
                            print("x"*30)
                            print("Tyvärr fel svar... Försök igen!")
                            print("x"*30)
                            wrong = wrong + 1
                            answered = answered +1
                            continue
                else:
                    print("x"*30)
                    print("Tyvärr fel svar. Finns bara en sån artist. Försök igen!")
                    print("x"*30)
                    wrong = wrong + 1
                    answered = answered +1
                    continue
        else:
            print("x"*30)
            print("Tyvärr fel svar. Finns bara ett sånt lag. Försök igen!")
            print("x"*30)
            wrong = wrong + 1
            answered = answered +1
            continue

def stats():
    print("*"*30)
    print("Du har svarat " + str(answered) + " gånger och har hittils " + str(wrong) + " fel.")
    print("*"*30)   

main()
```

Comment: `question()` should take question and answer from call parameters and not contain it self and it shouldn't call `main()`

Comment: Personally I would avoid using globals and make a class. That way passing variables and other items through self.variable makes something like this a little easier imo. Also you avoid globals.

Comment: If you are just looking for another way to close your python program without using sys.exit() you can simply use exit() or exit(404). If you need a full solution that would work I would be happy to help you code one out a little earlier. Also, since its a sequential series of questions, I do not think there is a necessity for so many while True: loops. Perhaps you can add 2 functions that update your variables for correct or wrong answers. Would be cleaner imo.